# test program flow generation losing options from main flow file on subsequent inits of test interface

Tags: origen-sdk

I pass in some parameters via the options hash in my main flow file:

```
Flow.create(environment: :ws, interface: 'MyTestLibrary::Interface', lib_version: Origen.top_level.lib_version) do
  import "components/bist"
  import "components/func"
  pass 1, softbin: 55
end
```

The problem is that the options do not stay persistent when other sub-flows are called.  Here is the pry session from the fist time the test interface is called:

```
    14: def initialize(options = {})
    15:   options = {
    16:     lib_version: nil
    18:   }.merge!(options)
 => 19:   binding.pry
[1] pry(#<MyTestLibrary::Interface>)> options
=> {:lib_version=>"3.14", :environment=>:ws, :interface=>"MyTestLibrary::Interface"}
```

However, here is the pry session from the second time the same breakpoint is hit:

```
[1] pry(#<MyTestLibrary::Interface>)> options
=> {:lib_version=>nil}
```

I guess I have a couple questions:

1. [Aren't the main flow options supposed to be persistent to
   sub-flows](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/#Re-usable_Flow_Snippets), with no added work on the user?
2. Why is the interface being re-initialized at all?  Seems like that should only occur once per generation command.

thx in advance

- EDIT *

@Ginty, you said in your answer the following:

*As far as the options passed into the top-level flow go, there is not really any guarantee about passing them into initialize. Rather the interface should create startup and shutdown methods if it wants to intercept them:*

But in the [docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/interface/#Required_Methods), I see the following stated:

*For an interface to run it must implement all of the methods that will be called by your flow. It is also customary to create an initialize method that will capture any options that are passed in to Flow.create (such as declaring the environment as probe in our flow example).*

Also, the startup method looks like a callback that gets run *after the interface is initialized*.  The information I am passing using the options hash is required *before the interface completes initialization*.  Isn't this creating a brittle run-order dependency the downstream user shouldn't need to worry about?
regards

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken about the options not being pass into initialize, I've re-written my answer below with the correct understanding behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have two top-level flows, and a flow component:

```rb
# program/prb1.rb
Flow.create interface: 'MyApp::Interface', temperature: 25 do
  import 'components/ram'
end

# program/prb2.rb
Flow.create interface: 'MyApp::Interface', temperature: 125 do
  import 'components/ram'
end

# program/components/_ram.rb
Flow.create do |options|

end
```

And this interface:

```rb
module MyApp
  class Interface
    include OrigenTesters::ProgramGenerators

    def initialize(options = {})
      puts "New interface!"
      puts "The temperature is: #{options[:temperature]}"
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Then if we were to generate both flows by running the prog gen on the program directory, `origen p program`, then we would see the interface get instantiated twice, once per top-level flow:

```
$ origen p program
[INFO]       0.006[0.006]    || **********************************************************************
[INFO]       0.010[0.004]    || Generating... prb1.rb
New interface!
The temperature is: 25
[INFO]       0.024[0.014]    || Generating... prb2.rb
New interface!
The temperature is: 125
[INFO]       0.052[0.028]    || Writing... prb1.tf
[INFO]       0.053[0.001]    || *** NEW FILE *** To save it:  cp output/testflow/mfh.testflow.group/prb1.tf .ref/prb1.tf
[INFO]       0.054[0.000]    || **********************************************************************
[INFO]       0.058[0.004]    || Writing... prb2.tf
[INFO]       0.059[0.001]    || *** NEW FILE *** To save it:  cp output/testflow/mfh.testflow.group/prb2.tf .ref/prb2.tf
[INFO]       0.059[0.000]    || **********************************************************************
Referenced pattern list written to: list/referenced.list
[INFO]       0.061[0.002]    || *** NEW FILE *** To save it:  cp list/referenced.list .ref/referenced.list
[INFO]       0.061[0.000]    || **********************************************************************
```

So, from the output we can see that the two instances of the interface get created, one per top-level flow that is generated, and the options passed to `Pattern.create` are passed into the interface's initialize method.

Note that no new interface is instantiated when the top-level flow imports a sub-flow/component.

Originally, a new interface instance was created every time `Flow.create` was encountered, which is the same time that the target is re-loaded. We did that because we had seen issues from an earlier implementation when the target was persisted for a whole flow. This led to some flow generation order dependencies starting to creep into some applications e.g. the output from prb1.rb was different when you generated it standalone vs. generating it at the same time as other flows.
So by starting from a clean slate each time, it eliminated the possibility of un-intentionally changing the output of a flow depending on what your target had done earlier.

Ultimately though, we found that within the context of generating a complete top-level flow, we really needed some persistent state to be available for things like tracking the test number count. So to compromise, we kept the target refresh on every `Flow.create` but refreshed the interface only upon encountering a new top-level `Flow.create`.

So far that has been working well in practice. However, if you feel that you need an interface that persists for a whole Origen program generation command, then perhaps you are coming across a use case that we haven't envisaged, or maybe there is another way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Open another question to give more details on that if required.

Comment: thanks for the very informative answer Ginty. This implementation will work for now.